# Capture Event of Subview Class in View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have two subviews with a UIbutton on them what I want is I want to capture the button click in my View Controller, and change the color of a view residing in it, one way is to create an object of View Controller in subview class and directly change the color of view but I dont want to do that can anybody tell me the other way around.

Comment: You should write out some code to describe your problem

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, add this:

```
[subview.button addTarget:self action:(buttonWasTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

where `subview.button` references the button inside the relevant subview. Also, add this event handler to the view controller:

```
- (void)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    // Button in subview was tapped; change the colour of the view here
}
```

and implement the logic you need to execute when the button is tapped.

Comment: Does this mean i have to remove the selector method from custom initialization of subview? because I have added the target action in subview initializer

Comment: If you no longer need it in the subview, then remove. You can actually add as many event handlers as you like to a control.

Comment: that's the thing I want to know how can I capture the event if selector method is already been declared in custom initialization.

Comment: You do it exactly as in my answer. `UIControl` (`UIButton`'s superclass) keeps an array of targets and actions for each event. You can add an event handler in your view's initialiser as well as as different selector the view controller.

Comment: one last query can you throw some more light regarding UIcontrol target action event array, would like to have more clarity on this for future

Comment: It's a `NSMutableArray` called `_targetActions`. It's declared right there in `UIControl.h`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neilco for your time and patience:)